# Robot Framework Selenium Mac OS X Lion Installation

Tags: selenium, osx-lion, robotframework

I am trying to run automation testing for website, but could not setup the system.
I am using Mac OS X Lion (10.7.2) and I want want to write some automated test with robot framework over the SeleniumLibrary which is provided. python 2.7 is installed and I use Firefox 9.

I want to run this repo on my local machine.
https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library

I have tried also the wiki quickstart over the robotframework website.
their is a pybot command line command and this could not been executed on my machine.

the selenium server has start.
*I hope somebody can help...*

**update:**
- for example I cant execute the ***pybot --version*** command.
- What is pybot?

Comment: What are the steps that you have taken to install the framework? Have you taken a look at the installation instructions: http://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/Installation

Comment: Don't expect to get much help if all you say is "it doesn't work". You need to supply an exact error message that you are seeing, if possible. I can confirm that at the time I write this, robot runs just fine on OSX Lion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at a similar set up on Linux (Fedora 15).

I think that at the time of writing, robotframework's seleniumlibrary does not support Firefox 9. Looking at the source, I think that the java code is waiting for a file called extensions.ini in the custom profile directory, whereas ff9 puts the extensions into a directory called extensions.

I suggest that you try an earlier version of ff.

To address the points made by others, you're going to need to post log output and possibly use the -log  flag to seleniumserver (eg when you launch the selenium server, java -jar  -log wibble)